# Admin new order email customization

Tags: customization, plugins, email

I'm using Woocommerce with Gravity forms and the Woocommerce gravity forms plug-in. I want to change the new order email (admin-new-order.php) so that instead of getting an email that lumps all products chosen via a gravity form into the left hand column making it very difficult to read, the products chosen are clearly itemised in the middle column. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the contents of all emails by overriding the templates from your (child) theme. Read the [documentation on Template Structure](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/) for more information on where all the files are located and how you can override them.

For example, say you would like to override the admin order notification, copy: the `templates/emails/admin-new-order.php` file from the WooCommerce plugin to `woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php` in your (child) theme and you can customise it there. This way it will upgrade safe, so the changes are not lost when updating the plugin.